# Drop rows from original Pandas dataframe if some GroupBy condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to construct a fast Pandas approach for dropping certain rows from a Dataframe when some condition is met. Specifically, I want to drop the first occurrence of some variable in the dataframe if some other value in that row is equal to 0. This is perhaps easiest explained by example:

```
foo = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])
bar = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': foo, 'bar':bar}) 

# So df is:
idx | foo | bar
0   1   1
1   1   0
2   1   1
3   1   0
4   1   1
5   1   0
6   1   1
7   1   0
8   1   1
9   1   0
10  1   1
11  2   0
12  2   1
13  2   0
14  2   1
15  3   1
16  3   1
17  3   0
18  3   1
```

I want to look at the first row when the 'foo' column is a new value, then drop it from the dataframe if the 'bar' value in that row = 0.

I can find when this condition is met using groupby:

```
df.groupby('foo').first()

# Result:
    bar
foo 
1   1
2   0
3   1
```

So I see that I need to drop the first row when foo = 2 (i.e. just drop row with index = 11 in my original data frame). I cannot work out, however, how to use this groupby result as a mask for my original data frame, since the shapes / sizes are different.

I found a related question on groupby modifications ([Drop pandas dataframe rows based on groupby() condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073496/drop-pandas-dataframe-rows-based-on-groupby-condition)), but in this example they drop ALL rows when this condition is met, whereas I only want to drop the first row.

Is this possible please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df.loc[~(df['foo'].ne(df['foo'].shift()) & df['bar'].eq(0))]
```

or

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset = 'foo') | df['bar'].ne(0)]
```

---

**clearly much better**

```
%%timeit
df.loc[~(df['foo'].ne(df['foo'].shift()) & df['bar'].eq(0))]
#970 µs ± 51.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each) each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset = 'foo') | df['bar'].ne(0)]
#1.34 ms ± 34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
df.loc[~df.index.isin(df.drop_duplicates(subset='foo').loc[lambda x: x.bar==0].index)]
#2.16 ms ± 109 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

if `foo` is like in your example:

```
%%timeit
df.loc[~(df['foo'].diff().ne(0)&df['bar'].eq(0))]
908 µs ± 15.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

or

```
%%timeit
df.loc[df['foo'].duplicated().add(df['bar']).ne(0)]
787 µs ± 15.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the first occurence of each new foo, check if bar is 0, then use it as a mask to filter the original df.

```
df.loc[~df.index.isin(df.drop_duplicates(subset='foo').loc[lambda x: x.bar==0].index)]
```

Or to use groupby:

```
(
    df.groupby('foo').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[int(x.bar.iloc[0]==0):])
    .reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
)
```

First approach is faster (2.71 ms) than the groupby method(3.93 ms) with your example.

Comment: Thanks, this works well and is nicely short. It takes ~2 secs to execute on a 10M sized dataset. Is this faster than using a groupby/transform operation do you think?

Comment: `I'm trying to construct a fast Pandas approach for dropping certain rows from a Dataframe` 
this has a lot of room for improvement