# Drop pandas dataframe rows based on groupby condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like below

```
    text    name    target
0   str1    name1   1
1   str1    name2   3
2   str1    name2   3
3   str2    name1   2
4   str2    name1   2
5   str2    name1   4
6   str3    name3   3
```

I need to remove those rows that have only one occurrence of a target class. In this case the row index `0` and `5` I need to remove because `1` and `4` appear only once.

I looked into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073496/drop-pandas-dataframe-rows-based-on-groupby-condition) and tried below:

```
df[df.groupby(['target']).transform('sum') > 1]
```

But that does not seem to work. Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `value_counts`, map back and filter:

```
print(df[df.target.map(df.target.value_counts()).gt(1)])
```

Output:

```
   text   name  target
1  str1  name2       3
2  str1  name2       3
3  str2  name1       2
4  str2  name1       2
6  str3  name3       3
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this suffices: filter out the rows where the target count is not greater than 1

```
df.groupby('target').filter(lambda x: x.count().gt(1).any())

    text    name    target
1   str1    name2   3
2   str1    name2   3
3   str2    name1   2
4   str2    name1   2
6   str3    name3   3
```